# SimpleXMLElement addChild issue with namespaces

Tags: php, simplexml, addchild

It's really quite simple. I'd like to [`$item->addChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php)`('media:thumbnail')` but it's not behaving as it removes 'media:'...

I am wondering how the following can be accomplished using SimpleXMLElement.

```
$thumbnail=$item->addChild('media:thumbnail');
$thumbnail->addAttribute('url', $row['url']);
$thumbnail->addAttribute('height', '81');
$thumbnail->addAttribute('width', '144');
//Output <media:thumbnail url="http://myurl.com/my.jpg" width="144" height="81" />
```

Comment: Your linked document indicates that `$namespace` should come as third parameter, instead of combined into the first one...

Answer (score 1):

Correct Answer:

```
    $thumbnail=('media:thumbnail', '', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    $thumbnail->addAttribute('url', $row['url']);
    $thumbnail->addAttribute('height', '81');
    $thumbnail->addAttribute('width', '144');
    //Output <media:thumbnail url="http://myurl.com/my.jpg" width="144" height="81" />
```

Comment: and if i want to insert a child to 'media:thumbnail' node?

Comment: @user1545914 You forgot `$thumbnail = $item->addChild(...)`
@Nikitas You just use `$thumbnail->addChild('tag', 'value')` or `$thumbnail->addChild('namespace:tag', 'value', 'http://ns1.example.com/ns/')`